# Pandas style: How to highlight diagonal elements

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I was wondering how to highlight diagonal elements of pandas dataframe using `df.style` method.

I found this official link where they discuss how to highlight maximum value, but I am having difficulty creating function to highlight the diagonal elements.

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,3,5,7],'c':[1,4,7,10],'d':[1,5,9,11]})

def highlight_max(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series yellow.
    '''
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in is_max]

df.style.apply(highlight_max)
```

This gives following output:
[image]

I am wanting a yellow highlight across the diagonal elements 1,3,7,11 only.

How to do that?

Comment: you should show your end result. what would you like to see; define diagonal result

Comment: As per suggestions, I accepted the answer of CJR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer is pretty good but I already wrote this so....

```
def style_diag(data):
    diag_mask = pd.DataFrame("", index=data.index, columns=data.columns)
    min_axis = min(diag_mask.shape)
    diag_mask.iloc[range(min_axis), range(min_axis)] = 'background-color: yellow'
    return diag_mask

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,3,5,7],'c':[1,4,7,10],'d':[1,5,9,11]})
df.style.apply(style_diag, axis=None)
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea the Axis=None argument was possible! This is a good solution, and should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

Using `axis=None` we can use numpy to easily set the diagonal styles (Credit for this goes to @CJR)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def highlight_diag(df):
    a = np.full(df.shape, '', dtype='<U24')
    np.fill_diagonal(a, 'background-color: yellow')
    return pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

df.style.apply(highlight_diag, axis=None)
```

[image]

---

Original, really hacky solution

```
a = np.full(df.shape, '', dtype='<U24')
np.fill_diagonal(a, 'background-color: yellow')
df_diag = pd.DataFrame(a,
                       index=df.index,
                       columns=df.columns)

def highlight_diag(s, df_diag):
    return df_diag[s.name]

df.style.apply(highlight_diag, df_diag=df_diag)
```

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use the `axis=None` parameter of the `df.style.apply` function in order to access the entire dataset:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,3,5,7],'c':[1,4,7,10],'d':[1,5,9,11]})

def highlight_diag(data, color='yellow'):
    '''
    highlight the diag values in a DataFrame
    '''
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    # create a new dataframe of the same structure with default style value
    df_style = data.replace(data, '')
    # fill diagonal with highlight color
    np.fill_diagonal(df_style.values, attr)
    return df_style

df.style.apply(highlight_diag, axis=None)
```

[image: output]