# Pandas style highlight diagonal and off diagonal elements

Tags: python, pandas

I was attempting to style highlight both the main diagonal and opposite main diagonal elements in pandas
dataframe.

I saw this link: [Pandas style: How to highlight diagonal elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916128/pandas-style-how-to-highlight-diagonal-elements)

This shows how to highlight the main diagonal but I was wondering how to highlight two diagonals with 
 two different colors?

Here is my data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'pred0': [10,   4],
                   'pred1': [0,   0],
            'total': [10,  4]},index=['true0','true1']
                   )

print(df)
       pred0  pred1  total
true0     10      0     10
true1      4      0      4
```

## My attempt

```
# Credit: ALLOLZ
def highlight_diag(df):
    a = np.full(df.shape, '', dtype='<U24')
    np.fill_diagonal(a, 'background-color: yellow')
    return pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

df.style.apply(highlight_diag, axis=None)
```

But this only hightlight one diagonal and does not highlight another diagonal.
How to highlight both diagonals.

## Required

```
          pred0          pred1         total
true0     10(green)      0(red)     10(no highlight)
true1      4(red)      0(green)      4(no highlight)
```

TIY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives what you want

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def highlight_diags(data):
    attr1 = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    attr2 = 'background-color: salmon'

    df_style = data.replace(data, '')
    np.fill_diagonal(df_style.values, attr1)
    np.fill_diagonal(np.flipud(df_style), attr2) 
    return df_style

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'pred0': [10,   4],
                   'pred1': [0,   0],
            'total': [10,  4]},index=['true0','true1']
                   )

df.style.apply(highlight_diags,axis=None)
```

[image]